# Is there an adverb for 'customised' or 'bespoke'

Tags: single-word-requests, adverbs

I am trying to convey the idea that something is done in a customised way but all I found was customarily ([link to Merriam-Webster definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/customarily)) which stems from customary so it's not what I need. Is there such a word?

It should fit in a sentence like this one:

> The items that I ____  manufactured are safely stored.

I know customised implies the creation of the object but I only do the manufacturing part, while the customisation is done by somebody else. I know the sentence can be reordered but I would like to know if there is an adverb I can use.

Comment: The items that have been customized  are safely stored.

Comment: @user240918 that was my approach initially but I feel like I have to reinforce the fact that they have been manufactured, hence the verb being 'manufactured' and needing adverb for customised

Comment: Customized implies that a product is  made or changed  according to the buyer's or user's needs. So “manufactured” is probably just redundant.

Comment: @user240918 I agree but I need to reinforce that it was me who manufactured them. I probably should make the example more closely resembling my case, thought a generalised but similar example would suffice

Comment: So, if I understand correctly: you manufactured them, and then someone else customized them, and then they got stored somewhere (by an unspecified entity)?  If the customizing was not part of the manufacturing, then applying an adverb that means "customized" to "manufactured" as in your example sentence is inappropriate.

Comment: @Hellion The customising _is_ part of the manufacturing process. Say I have a client that asked for both customised and standard items and he provides me with the customisation details which allows me to do both sets of items. After I finished the work and the client comes to ask for details about the customised ones that's where I need to mention the items that have been manufactured based on the customisation details provided. I know I can change the order, but I am a sucker for specific highly accurate words and happened to hit a snag when needed the adverb.

Comment: Is it a custom order or are these custom items, or both? Do you mean that it was a custom order of some sort, or that it was a regular order of custom-made items? Why do you need an adverb? Why aren’t these just custom items that you made for someone and safely stored?

Comment: @tchrist It is a regular order of custom-made items. However, I don't just store _some_ custom-made items, but items that I [insert adverb for custom here] manufactured for my client and then stored them away. I am starting to feel that the simple request for an adverb is causing some unintended frustration.. apologies if that's the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option is probably ***[specially](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/specially)***

> 2a : for a special purpose
>   dresses made specially for the occasion
>
> 2b : in particular : SPECIFICALLY
>   made specially for you

Thus

> The items that have been specially manufactured are safely stored.

or more succinctly

> Your specially-manufactured items are safely stored.

You have to be careful, because people can misuse "specially" when they mean "[especially](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/especially)", which has a different meaning.

Another option is ***individually***. The adjective *[individual](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/individually)* has a sense

> 1b.  Intended for one person

If two words are OK, you could go with ***to specification*** or its abbreviation *"to spec"*.  The noun [specification](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/specification) has the sense

> 2a: a detailed precise presentation of something or of a plan or proposal for something

With this one you could specify whose specification(s):

> The items 
>    have been manufactured *to your specifications*, and are safely stored.

(All quotations from Merriam-Webster).

Comment: I feel like this is a decent enough alternative since it seems I've nothing else, so I will go with it. Thanks for the time and effor put in reading and answering the post.